# Asynchronous NSImage download: first image has infinite loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, react-native

I'm trying to make a module for react-native using [NYTPhotoViewer](https://github.com/NYTimes/NYTPhotoViewer) and asynchronous image downloading. It works, but first image never stops to animate loading when the other downloads and shows. Interesting, that if I swipe some images (2 and more), the first image will render. The code is here:

```
#import <NYTPhotoViewer/NYTPhotosViewController.h>
#import "NYTImageViewer.h"
#import "NYTExamplePhoto.h"

@interface NYTImageViewer () <NYTPhotosViewControllerDelegate>
  @property (nonatomic) NSArray *photos;
@end

@implementation NYTImageViewer

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(open:(NSArray *)urls)
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSArray *photos = addPhotos(urls);

    NYTPhotosViewController *photosViewController = [[NYTPhotosViewController alloc] initWithPhotos:photos];

    UIViewController *ctrl = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];

    [ctrl presentViewController:photosViewController animated:TRUE completion: nil];
  });
}

NSArray* addPhotos(NSArray *urls) {
  NSMutableArray *photos = [NSMutableArray array];
  for (int i = 0; i < [urls count]; i++) {
    NYTExamplePhoto *photo = [[NYTExamplePhoto alloc] init];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
      NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urls[i]]];
      if ( imageData == nil )
        return;
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        photo.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
      });
    });
    [photos addObject:photo];
  }

  return photos;
}
@end
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: did you tried `[photo setNeedsDisplay:YES]` right after `photo.image = ...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't/can't load that way from a remote URL, and with the `dispatch_async` it's generating the expected behavior:

`NSData * _data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urls[i]]];`

You must use `NSURLSession` or `NSURLConnection` via asynchronous method for remote calls, and you'll have to handle recursion at the callback.